Vue3ヘッダーボタン操作でモーダルの表示場所をメインコンテンツに表示したいがヘッダーから抜け出せない
Vue3でヘッダーコンポーネントとメインコンポーネントを分けて作成しています。ヘッダーにボタンを配置して押すとモーダルがヘッダー以外に表示するという仕組みを作りたいです。
モーダルコンポーネントはメインコンポーネントに配置してヘッダーのボタンと繋がればうまく行きそうですがうまくいかずで。またモーダルはメインコンテンツの範囲だけで表示したいのでこれはサイズ指定すれば何とかなりそうですが、スクロールバーが消えず動いてします。
今無理やりメインコンポーネントにボタンを作りその位置をヘッダーにずらして表示させて事を凌いだのですが、流石にこれでは。。。
<template>
 <header/>←こちらにボタンがあり
 <main/> ←ここに<modal/>を配置
<template>

